# when i try to connect ec2 instances via ssh it says no such file or dic

Tags: aws-ec2-instance-connect

I download pem file while launching t2.micro instance. When I try to connect it via ssh it say no such a file in directory. But am sure that pem file is in directory.

```
$ chmod 400 web-dev-key.pem
  chmod: cannot access ‘web-dev-key.pem’: No such file or directory
```